# mongodb: create secure password with c#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm sorry if this are trivial questions but I just don't know how to do it really good :D

I'm using the official c#-mongodb-driver.

- 1 Question

Mongodb is storing the users password in cleartext right? So I have to take care about secure passwords? What is the best way to do it with c#?

Is this ok (found something similar in the obsolete addUser-Method in the driver-source)?

```
        var securePassword = new PasswordEvidence(password).SecurePassword;

        var userCommand = new CommandDocument
        {
            { "createUser", username },
            { "pwd", securePassword.ToString() },
            { "digestPassword", false },
            { "customData", new BsonDocument()},
            { "roles", new BsonArray()}
        };

        var result = Database.RunCommand(userCommand);
```

- 2 Question

the c#-driver is using the key "digestPassword" but I could't find any documentation for this. Any ideas what this means and why it is not documented properly?

- 3 Question

How can I check if the entered user/password-combination is correct without access to admin-database (no access to db.system.users.find()) ? are there any helper methods? I couldn't find one...

Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mongodb is storing the users password in cleartext right? So I have to take care about secure passwords?

For the default authentication in MongoDB (aka `MONGODB-CR` or "challenge-response auth") the passwords are stored internally as the hex encoding of `MD5( <username> + ":mongo:" + <password_text> )`. They are sent by drivers over the wire in digest form (see answer to your next question, below) rather than in clear text.

You should always care about choosing secure passwords and properly locking down your MongoDB deployment. The MongoDB documentation has a rather comprehensive [section on Security](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/) including risk management strategies and access control tutorials.

> the c#-driver is using the key "digestPassword" but I could't find any documentation for this. Any ideas what this means and why it is not documented properly?

The `digestPassword` is documented as part of how to [Implement Authentication in a Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/implement-authentication-in-driver/) and isn't a detail you normally need to be concerned with unless you are implementing a driver.

Drivers use a two step process for authentication:

1) request a hexadecimal [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) to use in subsequent authentication requests

2) authenticate using a message digest that combines the nonce and the password digest

> Is this ok (found something similar in the obsolete addUser-Method in the driver-source)?

The addUser method was deprecated in favour of the `createUser` command which is the newer implementation featuring roles.

I would strongly recommend using the [documented C# driver API](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/) rather than trying to reimplement the lower level driver commands.

> How can I check if the entered user/password-combination is correct without access to admin-database (no access to db.system.users.find()) ? are there any helper methods? I couldn't find one...

You can check the user/password combination by attempting to authenticate with it. You will also have to consider whether the user's roles grant appropriate permissions to run requested commands (if not, your application will have to handle the auth exception).

There are a full set of [User and Role Management](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-user-role-management/) helpers in the `mongo` shell if you want to view or manage authentication details (and assuming you have the appropriate privileges to do so).

Comment: sorry for my late answer. Thanks for this detailed answer!!! I will not try to implement things from the driver, but unfortunatelly the driver doesn't have f.e. a "createUser"-Method implemented. So i will use the documentCommand instead.

Comment: I have one more question about checking user credentials: I'm using this:  var adminConnector = new MongoDbConnection("mongodb://testuser:testpw@localhost/testdb"); I can put any password and it will not fail till I'm querying over a collection f.e. Is there a way to immediatelly check the user/password?

Comment: @TobiasKoller: [`createUser`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/createUser/) is the server command being used in your example in the question description. For efficiency, C# (and most of the drivers) will wait until you send a query or command before establishing the authenticated connection. The simplest query you can run to check the connection is a [`Ping()`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/4df96e2d-3273-1075-23df-6baea97942c3.htm).

Comment: @TobiasKoller If you want to check something more specific to the user role/privileges you have created, [GetCollectionNames()](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/aa54042b-8014-a9d8-06f0-4b090a634cc9.htm) or similar may be a more suitable query to run. If your application needs to use multiple users during a session you should also look into the [MongoCredential class](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-csharp-driver/).

Comment: Ping() is what I was looking for. It will return an exception it the credentials are incorrect and another if the server is not availabe.

Comment: Ping() is what I was looking for. It will return an exception it the credentials are incorrect and another if the server is not availabe. I really need to create 2 connections. one default-admin to check usercredentials before the user connection executes some CRUD-action and the 2. is the user-connection. I can't use the MongoCredentials for multiple-user because in my case the user would always have admin-rights ;)